# IE WebControls TreeView - web application javascript problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript, treeview

I am using the old `Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls` `TreeView` control. When running under a Web application the `treeview.GetChildren()` method through an

> object or property not supported error

yet the same code in an ASP.NET 2.0 website project runs fine.

Has anyone encountered this issue? There is almost nothing on the Web about this control...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Because the web controls completely suck dude.
Use javascript! Not that horrible non-standard-compliant stuff...